# Properly using xr packge with hyperref package

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, xr

I have this two tex files, where I want to refer a equation (just the number) to another file. So, I am using `xr` package. Here's the two files

`doc1.tex`

```tex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
    
    \section{New Section}

    \begin{eqnarray}
        x=2
        \label{eq:test}
    \end{eqnarray}
    
    
    Equation \ref{eq:test}
    
\end{document}
```

`doc2.tex`

```tex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument{doc1}


\begin{document}
    
Equation \ref{eq:test}
    
\end{document}
```

This gives in `doc2.pdf` `Equation 1`

Now, I if modify the `doc.tex` to use the `hyperref` package,
`doc1.tex`

```tex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
    
    \section{New Section}

    \begin{eqnarray}
        x=2
        \label{eq:test}
    \end{eqnarray}
    
    Equation \ref{eq:test}
        
\end{document}
```

and compile everything, in `doc2.pdf` this changes to `Equation 1New Sectionequation.1.1`.
Why `xr` package gets messed up with the `hyperref` package and how to properly use the `xr` package with the `hyperref`.
NOTE: I don't need/want to link the Equation 1 in the `doc2.pdf`, I just want the number to be shown there. I need to use `hyperref` package just for internal references inside the `doc1.pdf` file.

Comment: Please try with `xr-hyper.sty` https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xr-hyper

Comment: How current is your latex?

Comment: In a current LaTeX it should work.